# ORDER BY gives ERROR: function array_position(text[], character varying) does not exist

Tags: postgresql, order-by, array, enum

I have a pretty basic categorical column in a Postgres database that is currently stored as VARCHAR. I can select a count of each with:

I though adding an `ORDER BY array_position()` would do it:

```
SELECT color, count(*)
FROM research
GROUP BY color 
ORDER BY array_position(ARRAY['Red','Orange','Yellow','Green','Blue'], color);
```

But I'm seeing a type error:

```
ERROR: function array_position(text[], character varying) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 98
```

What do I need to cast `color` as so I can use the `array_position` function to order it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Sample data

You have a table like,

```
CREATE TABLE research(colors)
  AS VALUES ('Blue'), ('Orange'), ('Yellow');
```

## `ENUM` type

You have an enumerated list of colors. So the easy thing here would be to use an [ENUM type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-enum.html)

```
CREATE TYPE colors AS ENUM ('Red','Orange','Yellow','Green','Blue');
```

Then

```
ALTER TABLE research
  ALTER COLUMN colors      -- myColorsColumn
  SET DATA TYPE colors
  USING (colors::colors);  -- myColorsColumn::NewType
```

Now it's faster, more efficient, and cleaner. MORE WIN. MORE JOY. Etc. `ENUM` are stored as 4-byte internally.

```
ORDER BY colors
```

Is all you'll need.

## Array Sort

But, you've got a God-given right to treat this like any other database that doesn't support ENUM types,

```
ORDER BY array_position(ARRAY['Red','Orange','Yellow','Green','Blue'], color);
```

**I think this is perfectly fine**, but I believe there is a limitation here in the implementation,

```
ARRAY['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Is essentially

```
ARRAY['foo', 'bar', 'baz']::text
```

This means you need to either ([speed doesn't matter as both options perform the same](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/201841/2639))

1. Make the `color` column of the native `text`. This can be done in the call, or you can actually modify the table and should. In PostgreSQL, nothing should be `varchar` without a limit (since that's just a parallel type for text), and very few things should be `varchar` with a limit (since there is no advantage)

   ```
   color::text            -- PostgreSQL sexy sexy cast
   CAST(color AS TEXT))   -- ANSI SQL standardized vanilla and boring
   ```
2. Or, you can construct the array itself as type `varchar[]`

   ```
   array_position(ARRAY['Red','Orange','Yellow','Green','Blue']::varchar[], color);
   ```

### Further notes

- In PostgreSQL, we wouldn't use `varchar` for `colors`. Even if you insist on not using an `ENUM` here (though I would), that should be `text`
- The `array_position` is a shorthand, I expect it to be substantially slower than a similar operation though

  ```
  CASE
    WHEN color='Red' THEN 1::smallint
    WHEN color='Orange' THEN 2::smallint
    WHEN color='Yellow' THEN 3::smallint
    ... etc
  END;
  ```

Comment: Why does `csvsql` default to VARCHAR if TEXT is preferred?

Comment: It doesn't. Someone likely made it `varchar` because they were ignorant about PostgreSQL (innocent mistake). In some databases like Microsoft SQL `text` carries a high overhead because it's stored as an out-of-line blob so they use things like `VARCHAR(max)` (and MySQL). In PostgreSQL, strings are stored as pstrings/varlena so we just `text`. No need to fake-constrict them and slow them down with length checks.

Comment: @EvanCarroll what is the difference between unlimited `varchar` and `text`?

Comment: @dezso projection is slower, and signatures don't align always (as seen here), and also convention/clarity.

Answer (score 0):

you have to cast the `text` type of the array you have defined to the character varying array `varchar[]`

```
SELECT color, count(*)
FROM research
GROUP BY color 
ORDER BY array_position(ARRAY['Red','Orange','Yellow','Green','Blue']::varchar[], color);
```