# Is there any slowdown in casting from varchar to text?

Tags: postgresql, performance, datatypes, type-conversion, varchar

In [writing this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/201839/2639), I'm just wondering if there is any slow down in casting from `varchar` to `text` or if that cast is just a compile-time trick. I've been told they're represented the same way and they're binary-coercable. Would it be faster to do

```
SELECT varchar1
FROM table
WHERE varchar1::text = 'foo';
```

Or,

```
SELECT varchar1
FROM table
WHERE varchar1 = 'foo'::varchar;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All tests done on PostgreSQL 9.5. On the matter of the cast,

## Sample Data

We first create a table with 100,000 rows with 3 varchar columns.

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS
  SELECT x::varchar AS x1, x::varchar AS x2, x::varchar AS x3
  FROM generate_series(1,1e6) AS gs(x);
```

## In `SELECT`

Then we try to the casts,

```
SELECT x1::text, x2::text, x3::text FROM foo;
Time: 476.825 ms

SELECT x1::text, x2::text, x3::text FROM foo;
Time: 501.092 ms

SELECT x1, x2, x3 FROM foo;
Time: 360.493 ms

SELECT x1, x2, x3 FROM foo;
Time: 373.647 ms
```

**Conclusion: substantial slowdown** it's not a compile type coercion.

## In `WHERE` clause

However, in the where conditional they seem to act effectively the same,

```
SELECT * FROM foo
WHERE x1::varchar = '5'::varchar;
```

Performs as well as,

```
SELECT * FROM foo
WHERE x1::text = '5';
```

And if I now run,

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE array_position(ARRAY['5', '6', '9'], x1::text) IS NOT NULL;

SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE array_position(ARRAY['5', '6', '9']::varchar[], x1) IS NOT NULL;
```

Both of them perform the same, so there is an optimization in the `WHERE` clause.